# After setting READ protection option byte value = CC (chip protection). NO STM32 target found

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide

After setting READ protection option byte value = CC (chip protection) I can't program the card anymore. CubeIDe and CubeProgrammer cannot find the device.

Anyone know how they can fix it thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have permanently disabled debug access on this chip, it can never be restored.  That is the whole point and only reason that you would ever write 0xCC.

See the appropriate page in the manual (eg: if you are using stm32f4 then it is section 3.7.3 of [RM0090](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00031020-stm32f405-415-stm32f407-417-stm32f427-437-and-stm32f429-439-advanced-arm-based-32-bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf))

Comment: I had not checked on the datasheet, I thought it could be a reversible operation and I tried out of curiosity. So the microcontroller can no longer be used to update the firmware in another way? Thanks for helping everyone

Comment: As 0___ has suggested, the firmware could update itself, but only if you have programmed a firmware that knows how to do that before you lock it.

Comment: It is reversible only in a few of the latest stm32. Like STM32U5. It has been shown it can be reversed through EMI vulnerabilities on some older chips like yours. However for your purpose it's a waste of time/money.

Comment: Thanks for the directions.
In fact I have a microcontroller of the STM32U585 family.
If you can give me more precise information on how to go back and be able to program the microcontroller I would be grateful.
Should I use CubeIDe or do I need to download some other program? Both CubeIde and CubeProgrammer do not see the microcontroller and I do not have access from the beginning and I would not know how to move or remove that fleg for example by going to write in a certain register since I cannot access it. It could be a hardware level mode by giving some voltage on appropriate pins

Answer (score 0):

This protection level disables debug interface permanently. Your chip is bricked and you need to buy another one.

If your application requires updates you need to write your own bootloader (or the app can upgrade itself) as only the program can reprogram the FLASH in this protection mode.

Comment: When you say: "If your application requires updates you need to write your own bootloader (or the app can upgrade itself) as only the program can reprogram the FLASH in this protection mode. "How can I update the microcontroller firmware, it is on a PCB not a development board" The microcontroller is from the U585 series. The other user's comment says that I can no longer use the microcontroller and update the firmware and also the datasheet if I understand correctly it says that it is an irreversible operation, so I have to throw away the micro

Comment: @Electronic_Firmware I would suggest to not use read protection if you do not understand how it works

Comment: @Electronic_Firmware you cant use any built-in mechanisms.